# Confidence interval for x-values given a probability in a logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, probability, logistic, confidence-interval

I'm facing the following problem:

I have done a logistical regression and the point on the x-axis, where both possible outcomes are equally likely (50%) is very important for my research. Getting this point wasn’t a problem. I’m offering two methods below.

Now I’d like to get a confidence interval around this x-value and I have no idea how this could be done, or if this is even possible at all. Looking at ggplot, standard errors are drawn, but with my understanding, those show the confidence interval for the values on the y-axis given a certain x-value and cannot be used for my problem.

I added some red lines manually to show, what I’m looking for and aligned them with the standard error. As explained above, even if I could get these 2 values, by using the standard error of ggplot, I think those would not be the confidence interval I’m looking for.

[image: ggplot]

Here is my code:

```
    library(ggplot2)  

    model <- glm(vs ~ mpg, data = mtcars, family = binomial)

    #Method 1

    findInt <- function(model, value) {
      function(x) {
        predict(model, data.frame(mpg=x), type="response", se.fit=TRUE)$fit  - value
      }
    }
    vline <- uniroot(findInt(model, .5), lower = -100, upper = 100)$root

    vline

    #Method 2

    p = 0.5
     (log(p/(1-p)) - coef(model)[1])/coef(model)[2]

    ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, vs)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      stat_smooth(method = "glm", method.args = list(family = "binomial"), se = TRUE) +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0.50, linetype=2) +
       geom_vline(xintercept = vline) +
       geom_vline(xintercept = 24.85, colour = "red") +
       geom_vline(xintercept = 17.9, colour = "red")
```

Comment: Intuitively I understand your meaning, and note that that as you point out the confidence intervals are for the model predictions, that is, the y-axis values only and not the x-axis values. Having said that, note that the vertical red lines you drew cross the upper and lower confidence intervals where their respective derivatives are equal to zero. If you can determine these derivatives and solve for the point where they are zero it might do what you want. I have never done this and offer the idea as a suggestion towards reaching your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I tried for quite some time to find the function from the upper and lower confidence interval, but wasn’t able to. And knowing, that even if I could find them, these values for the interval wouldn’t correspond to anything meaningful made me stop this endeavor. 
After some more research I might try to get CI by bootstrapping.