# Logistic regression - Confidence interval for x axis

Tags: logistic, confidence-interval, fitting, curve-fitting, logistic-distribution

My question is very similar to the post [Confidence interval for x-values given a probability in a logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332689/confidence-interval-for-x-values-given-a-probability-in-a-logistic-regression)
where ultimately no answer was given. I have also posted a similar version on the mathematica stack exchange,
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272716/logistic-regression-confidence-interval-for-x-axis?noredirect=1#comment681054_272716
, but it was suggested that I repost here.

Based on the comments below, I found it necessary to include more detail in how the data is generated

As an example consider the scenario where a cannonball is fired at a wall. There are only two outcomes: the wall collapses (1) and the wall does not collapse (0). I'm interested in the probability that the wall collapses as a function of the cannonball velocity. It is reasonable to expect that the probability vs velocity will have an S shape. Nevertheless, it is just an example.

I have a set of test data:

```
dataUpDown = {{24, 0}, {29, 0}, {34, 0}, {39, 0}, {44, 0}, {49, 1}, {44, 1}, {39, 
  1}, {34, 1}, {29, 0}, {34, 0}, {39, 0}, {44, 0}, {49, 0}, {54, 
  0}, {59, 1}, {54, 0}, {59, 0}, {64, 1}, {59, 0}, {64, 1}, {59, 
  0}, {64, 0}, {69, 1}, {64, 1}, {59, 1}, {54, 1}, {49, 1}, {44, 
  0}, {49, 1}, {44, 1}, {39, 0}, {44, 0}, {49, 0}, {54, 0}, {59, 
  1}, {54, 1}, {49, 0}, {54, 0}, {59, 1}, {54, 1}, {49, 0}, {54, 
  0}, {59, 0}, {64, 1}, {59, 1}, {54, 1}, {49, 1}, {44, 1}, {39, 0}}
```

where the numbered pair will be referred to as $\{v_i,y_i\}$. Here $y_i$ is a binary variable which only can take the values $0\,\text{or}\,1$ and $v_i$ is a continous quantity. In the example above $v_i$ is the cannonball velocity, and $y_i$ determines whether the wall collapses $(y_i=1)$ or not $(y_i=0)$. The data above is generated with the so--called up/down procedure which works like this:

1. Start with some initial velocity and fire
2. If the wall collapses, decrease the velocity with a fixed amount
3. If the wall does not collapse, increase the velocity with a fixed amount
4. Step 2 and 3 is then repeated until a certain number of shots (e.g. 50) have been performed.

We imagine, unrealistically, that if the wall collapses, it is immediately repaired. In reality, there will be some uncertainty in decreasing/increasing the velocity by a specific amount. As a consequence the velocity steps might not be uniform in an experiment.

In mathematica this data generating procedure can be implemented as:

```
(*UP-DOWN TEST*)
(*Velocity vs perforation*)
s = 13; \[Mu] = 50; 
step = 5; error = 0.2;
(*Generate data according to up-down test*)

dataUpDown = {};

Table[
  If[shotNumber == 1, V0 = \[Mu] - 2 s,];
  
  perf = RandomVariate[
     BernoulliDistribution[1/(1 + E^(-((V0 - \[Mu])/s)))], 1][[1]];
  
  If[
   perf == 1,
   AppendTo[dataUpDown, {V0, perf}]; 
   V0 = V0 - step,
   AppendTo[dataUpDown, {V0, perf}]; 
    V0 = V0 + step];
  
  , {shotNumber, 1, 50}];
```

Whether or not the wall collapses is determined by an underlying "true" probability function of the form
$$ P(y=1|v) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-\frac{v-\mu}{s}}} $$
where I decide on $\mu = 50$ and $s=13$ for concreteness. Specifically the fate of the wall is determined by using a single random Bernoulli draw, where the probability input is the the true model above and the output is collapse (1) or not collapse (0).

Since the data is binary I want to to a logistic curve fitting with the function
$$P(y=1|v) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-\left(\alpha + \beta v\right)}}$$

I can then use some programming language (e.g. mathematica) to obtain a logistic regression by writing something like

```
logit = LogitModelFit[dataUpDown, x, x];
```

I can define a 95% confidence interval for the probabilities by writing something like this

```
(* Get predictions and upper and lower confidence limits for a + b*x *)
pred = Table[1 - 1/(1 + Exp[parms.{1, x[[i]]}]), {i, 101}];
lower = Table[1 - 1/(1 + Exp[parms.{1, x[[i]]} - 1.96 Sqrt[{1, x[[i]]}.cov.{1, x[[i]]}]]), {i, 101}];
upper = Table[1 - 1/(1 + Exp[parms.{1, x[[i]]} + 1.96 Sqrt[{1, x[[i]]}.cov.{1, x[[i]]}]]), {i, 101}];
```

I have then constructed a confidence interval for the sum $\alpha + \beta x$ and used the logistic mapping to convert it to the probability interval.

However, my question is how can I obtain a confidence interval on the $x$ values? I.e what is the uncertainty in the velocity, specifically in certain velocity quantiles.

The question pops up naturally if one want to calculate the velocity $v_i = v_{50}$ where $v_{50}$ is the velocity required to have a 50% chance of making the wall collapse. By extension, I'm also interested in confidence intervals for quantities such as $v_{60}$, $v_{70}$, $v_{80}$, $v_{90}$, i.e. a confidence interval on the velocities.

Comment: The comment on the linked question applies here too: you can have a confidence interval for the probability given an $x$ value, but what I think you are looking for is a confidence interval for quantile estimates

Comment: Thanks for the comment. A general form of the confidence interval for quantiles such as $X_{95}, X_{70}, X_{50},\dots$ would be useful. I guess it is strongly related to a pointwise confidence interval for the $x_i$. Do you know how to do something like this for the logistic curve fitting procedure?

Comment: My point is that your original observations and regression assumed that the $x_i$ (distance to the target in your particular example) were measured accurately so do not have any uncertainty.  Estimating distance by whether you hit the target or not seems a strange thing to do

Comment: @Henry I think (or at least until just earlier today) that the OP is interested in a "calibration interval" or "inverse regression":  Given a proportion of success, what is a confidence interval for the predictor variable to achieve that success.  But today's question at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272804/implementing-a-way-of-generating-binary-data-for-use-in-a-logistic-regression implies that the data generating procedure is not giving a set of independent observations (i.e., the data given above).

Comment: Thanks JimB, I will update the question in an attempt to make it more clear. The data above should indeed be interpreted to arise from some procedure.